# javascript, split string per length

Tags: javascript, html, string

I change number to string

```
ex) 

721,011 => seven hundred twenty-one thousand eleven

21,011 => twenty-one thousand eleven
```

and i found split per three words

https://gist.github.com/hendriklammers/5231994

but it is splited at first word

```
 721,011 => [721, 011] (It is perfect)
 21,011 => [210, 11] (It is not perfect, wanna [21, 011])
 2123011 => [212, 301, 1] (It is not perfect, wanna [2, 123, 011])
 21230ef11 => [212, 301, 1] (It is not perfect, I'll accept only integer , wanna [2, 123, 011]), (using fucntion num.toString().replace(/\D/g, "") )
```

how to split string per length?

is it only reverse string and re reversing?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Barmar now I'm started develop and find how to split words

Comment: "split string per length" is not clear at all what you want.  Please show sample input and desired output for several different inputs.

Comment: @kai What does that mean? I asked you to show the code that isn't working the way you want it. You also need to explain better what you're trying to do.

Comment: _not perfect_? Do you mean _wrong_?

Comment: @Barmar I wanna split per three length words   "123456789" is split per three words [123,456,789] and "1234567" is [1,234,567]

Comment: Put that explanation in the question. And put your code that isn't working in the question. Then we'll probably reopen it.

Comment: Not a perfect match, but there should be enough here to help: [*How to print a number with commas as thousands separators in JavaScript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: Most English speakers would say "twenty one thousand and eleven". No, you don't have to reverse the string.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't understand your question entirely wrong, a simple

```
var a = '21,011'
var b = a.split(',');
```

should do the job.

Comment: my text is "21,011" or "21011" or "2938dkdj"(change 2938)

Comment: No, I think (?) he wants to split a number without commas into groups of three digits, for input into his algorithm to convert the number into words.